additional domain header and footer in IOS PWA
I have created a PWA using react which is dynamically updating values with respect to domain. But, getting a header and footer in ios for PWA. for android when I try to install PWA from browser i am getting two option like install and add to  homescreen.
please help me to solve this pwa issue, thanks in advance.
IOS PWA
these are my meta tags
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,initial-scale=1"/>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/nprogress.min.css"/>
<title>HEADER</title>
<link rel="icon" href="{{s3 url}}">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="{{s3 url}}">
<meta name="description" content="HEADER">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffd3d3">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="HEADER">
<link rel="manifest" id="manifest-sheet" href="data:application/json;charset=utf...">

manifest file data
{
    "short_name": "HEADER",
    "name": "HEADER",
    "icons": [
        {
            "sizes": "72x72",
            "type": "image/png",
            "purpose": "maskable any",
            "src": "blob:http://localhost:3000/efc8ab68-1f73-4704-84d9-3705a4231443"
        },
        {
            "sizes": "96x96",
            "type": "image/png",
            "purpose": "maskable any",
            "src": "blob:http://localhost:3000/055600ae-0ef4-4a13-9fbf-bef3a88142bf"
        },
        {
            "sizes": "128x128",
            "type": "image/png",
            "purpose": "maskable any",
            "src": "blob:http://localhost:3000/9c083512-801d-493f-abb2-05ad279c0325"
        },
        {
            "sizes": "144x144",
            "type": "image/png",
            "purpose": "maskable any",
            "src": "blob:http://localhost:3000/d5019eda-6fa1-432d-a208-86d6299e18ca"
        },
        {
            "sizes": "152x152",
            "type": "image/png",
            "purpose": "maskable any",
            "src": "blob:http://localhost:3000/4f5e78b0-527c-4221-b0b7-e2e0002b3ef8"
        },
        {
            "sizes": "192x192",
            "type": "image/png",
            "purpose": "maskable any",
            "src": "blob:http://localhost:3000/0b4fcee2-dd1d-4f84-896c-daa938f243f8"
        },
        {
            "sizes": "384x384",
            "type": "image/png",
            "purpose": "maskable any",
            "src": "blob:http://localhost:3000/881f5887-de4d-462f-8e35-45dec69a4c2b"
        },
        {
            "sizes": "512x512",
            "type": "image/png",
            "purpose": "maskable any",
            "src": "blob:http://localhost:3000/fb6c9bf1-661d-4ff3-8b0e-b873622d8da9"
        }
    ],
    "start_url": "http://localhost:3000/",
    "display": "fullscreen",
    "theme_color": "#feeb0b",
    "background_color": "#ffffff",
    "orientation": "any",
    "features": [
        "Cross Platform",
        "fast",
        "simple"
    ],
    "categories": [
        "utilities"
    ]
}

I need to remove the header and footer comes in ios PWA
